# constraining a table field -> not duplicate value, not a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

> How to constrain a column in my table so it can't have two or more
>   similar values at a time and it isn't a primary key ?

Should I use `CHECK` or `CONSTRAINT` or ... ? what's the right way to achieve that ?

**note :** I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_idx1 ON foo (bar)
```

MySQL does not implement check constraints.

Comment: A `CHECK CONSTRAINT` couldn't be used for a "unique constraint" anyway. And MySQL does have `CONSTRAINTS` e.g. a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - You are right. I've expanded the answer with a more careful explanation.